# Write an Effective query for django for a FOR Loop?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I need to get number of policies bought in each month from these model

```
class Insurance(models.Model):
  #other fields..
  date_purchased_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)    
  customer_region = models.CharField(
    max_length=10, choices=RegionType.choices)
```

so i have written a views to get a response

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def chart_data(request):
    # structure of the op should be all the months from 1 to 12
    #  [{"month": 1,"count": 100,}, { "month:2", "count":20}]

    filtered_data = []
    for i in range(1, 13):
        query = Insurance.objects.filter(date_purchased_on__month=i).count()
        data = {
            "month": i,
            "count": query
        }
        filtered_data.append(data)
        
    return Response(filtered_data)
```

now the **problem is this query hits the database every time** its like 12 times. is there a way to handle this to get in a ***single query or to reduce it***

and my logger results

```sql
(0.000) SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "insurance_insurance" WHERE EXTRACT('month' FROM "insurance_insurance"."date_purchased_on") = 1; args=(1,); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "insurance_insurance" WHERE EXTRACT('month' FROM "insurance_insurance"."date_purchased_on") = 2; args=(2,); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "insurance_insurance" WHERE EXTRACT('month' FROM "insurance_insurance"."date_purchased_on") = 3; args=(3,); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "insurance_insurance" WHERE EXTRACT('month' FROM "insurance_insurance"."date_purchased_on") = 4; args=(4,); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "insurance_insurance" WHERE EXTRACT('month' FROM "insurance_insurance"."date_purchased_on") = 5; args=(5,); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "insurance_insurance" WHERE EXTRACT('month' FROM "insurance_insurance"."date_purchased_on") = 6; args=(6,); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "insurance_insurance" WHERE EXTRACT('month' FROM "insurance_insurance"."date_purchased_on") = 7; args=(7,); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "insurance_insurance" WHERE EXTRACT('month' FROM "insurance_insurance"."date_purchased_on") = 8; args=(8,); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "insurance_insurance" WHERE EXTRACT('month' FROM "insurance_insurance"."date_purchased_on") = 9; args=(9,); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "insurance_insurance" WHERE EXTRACT('month' FROM "insurance_insurance"."date_purchased_on") = 10; args=(10,); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "insurance_insurance" WHERE EXTRACT('month' FROM "insurance_insurance"."date_purchased_on") = 11; args=(11,); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "insurance_insurance" WHERE EXTRACT('month' FROM "insurance_insurance"."date_purchased_on") = 12; args=(12,); alias=default
```

Comment: use aggregation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: im not sure how to replicate the same using aggregate. if you show me some way to do this it will be great to implement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the month and order by that month with an [**`ExtractMonth`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractMonth):

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth

Insurance.objects.values(month=ExtractMonth('date_purchased_on')).annotate(
    count=Count('pk')
).order_by('month')
```

This will product a `QuerySet` of dictionaries that look like:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'month': 6, 'count': 100 },
    {'month': 7, 'count': 20 }
]>
```

Months for which there is no `Insurance` object will *not* be included in the `QuerySet`. You thus might have to *post-process* it and include records with `'count': 0` for these.

Comment: is there a way to get a response for region in every month how many policies have been bought?

{ 'east': [all month data in a list], 'west':[all month data in a list],  'north' : [all month data in a list] , 'south': [all month data in a list]}

Comment: Yes, you add `'customer_region'` as first parameter of `.values(..)` and in the `.order_by('customer_region', 'month')`.

Comment: @Gokulaselvan: so 
`Insurance.objects.values('customer_region', month=ExtractMonth('date_purchased_on')).annotate(count=Count('pk')).order_by('customer_region', 'month')`.

Comment: @Gokulaselvan: but the same comment applies: it will not contain records for regions and months if for that region-month combination, there are no `Insurance`s.